# OBD2 - Reading Service 01 PID 00

Tags: bluetooth, serial-port, obd-ii

With my Windows 10 PC, I am connected to OBD2, over Bluetooth 4.0 as a serial device over the COM-Port.

I am sending the following command: `Service 01 PID 00` - my command is: `0100\r`

[Services / Modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs#Services_/_Modes): Show current data

[Standard PIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs#Service_01) PID 00: [Show PIDs supported](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs#Service_01_PID_00) [0x01 - 0x20] (1..32)

My first car, Opel Astra, response: `010041 00 D8 3B 20 13`

my second car, Mercedes Benz, response:

Version A:

```
Data Received:
0100
Data Received:
41 00 BE 3C A8 13
41 00 98 18 00 01
41 00 98 18 00 01
```

Version B:

```
Data Received:
0100
Data Received:
41 00 98 18 00 01
41 00 BE 3C A8 13
41 00 98 18 00 01
```

Version C:

```
Data Received:
0100
Data Received:
41 00 98 18 00 01
41 00 98 18 00 01
41 00 BE 3C A8 13
```

If I am sending `0100` to the Opel Astra, I am getting always the same response `D8 3B 20 13`, I think it looks good and makes sense.

If I am sending `0100` the the Mercedes Benz, I am getting Version A or B or C. At the same connection time, it is mixed, like: A,A,C or A,C,C - Why it is not just `98 18 00 01` or just `BE 3C A8 13`

The answer from the Opel is very clear, but, how can I evaluate this answer from the Mercedes?

I don't understand why I get more than 4 bytes, why I get different 4 bytes and why in a different order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Mercedes has multiple ECUs that answer to OBD2 requests. Let yourself show the addresses by turning headers on: Assuming you're using an ELM327-compatible device, it's `ATH1\r`.

If you want to target only one ECU, you may set the headers. On an ELM327-compatible device and CAN, it's `ATSH7E0` and `ATCRA7E8` for physical addressing the first ECU.

Comment: thank you! After your answer I found this article very helpfull [Received frames from vehicles with multiple ECU chips](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/22982/received-frames-from-vehicles-with-multiple-ecu-chips)

Comment: For the sake of commpleteness [ELM327 OBD to RS232 Interpreter](https://www.elmelectronics.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/ELM327DS.pdf)